# Difference in network traffic between webapi and direct database access?

Tags: database, networking, webapi, traffic

General question.  Which option would have less network traffic.

**Option 1**:  A single database connection to a WebAPI, with multiple clients communicating via the API using the standard request / return data.

**Option 2**:  Each client having direct read only access to the database with their own connections, and reading the data directly.

My expectation is that with only a single user, the direct database approach would have less traffic, but for each additional user the API would have a smaller incremental increase in traffic over the direct database.

However I have no evidence to back this up.  Just hoping somebody may know of a resource which has this data already, or has done the experiment themselves (as my google fu is failing me)